# Pods are not getting created on one of the agent node in Kubernetes

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-container-service, kubernetes-helm

I am using kubernetes cluster with 3 master and 3 agents which is created using Azure container service (ACS).

I have created the 50+ deployments using helm with one pod each and it is working fine. Out of three agents, only two agents are hosting half deployments on it. The third agent doesn't have any pod created on it except system/kubernetes created pods.

Any inputs will be helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you share third agent's logs?  kubelet's log on the node

Answer (score 0):

run the `kubectl describe node <3rdagent name>` command and check `Taints` is set for `NoSchedule`

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/taint-and-toleration/

if not you can label this node and schedule the pod on this with label see its runs on this node.

Comment: Node has "Taints: <none>"

Comment: ok, then try assign pod to this node and test. https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/assign-pod-node/